# apt upgrade very large, how can I see size of individual packages?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, ubuntu-16.04

When I usually log in to server and do `apt upgrade` its usually max a few hundred mb is required for update.  I just logged in to one of my vps that only has virtualmin installed and the `apt upgrade` is reporting it needs 16.8gb which is more space than I have available.

This doesn't seem right.  How can I see what packages are requiring so much space?

Comment: 16GB is huge - I think you're right to suspect something is up. I can't see a way to get this breakdown with `apt` or `apt-get`. You could do a laborious manual search by looking at each package to be upgraded and issuing `apt install <package>` (or a list of packages) - that would tell you the total download size for <package> and its dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Install *apt-show-versions* package on the machine:

`$ sudo apt-get install apt-show-versions -y`

Get a list of packages that are upgradable:

`$ apt-show-versions -u`

The following shall provide you with a list of upgradable packages and their correspnding size (bytes) in ascending order:

```
$ for i in `/usr/bin/apt-show-versions -u | tr ' ' / | cut -f1,6 -d'/' | tr / =` ; do echo -n $i ; sudo apt-cache show $i | grep '^Size:' | cut -d: -f2 ; done | sort -k2 -n
```

A quick break down of the above command:

- `/usr/bin/apt-show-versions -u | tr ' ' / | cut -f1,6 -d'/' | tr / =` provide a list of packages with their upgradable version in *packagename=version* format
- `sudo apt-cache show $i | grep '^Size:'` fetch the size of the package
- `sort -k2 -n` display formatted output in ascending order

---

Find out security updates:

`$ apt-show-versions -u | grep security`

It is generally a good practise to configure security auto-updates:

`$ sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades -y`

If *unattended-upgrades* is already installed, and you like to ensure it is configured to automatically apply security updates:

`$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades`

Comment: How does this answer the question? I have tried this and I don't see any way of getting **sizes**.

Comment: Does the Size: reported by apt-cache correspond to the size that would need to be downloaded for an update? I thought it was the size for a new install, and that these wouldn't necessarily be the same.

Comment: One system of mine reports `Need to get 75.0 MB of archives` from `apt upgrade` but your command results in a total of 2736502 = 2672MB approx

Comment: Edit of your command to show just total: `for i in \`/usr/bin/apt-show-versions -u | tr ' ' / | cut -f1,6 -d'/' | tr / =\` ; do apt-cache show $i | grep '^Size:' | cut -d: -f2 ; done | paste -sd+ | bc`

Comment: 2736502 bytes = 2.736502 megabytes and even that is not close enough to 75.0 MB. I can only speculate that you have a few packages already available in /var/cache/apt. I tried this on two separate servers: `for i in $(/usr/bin/apt-show-versions -u | tr ' ' / | cut -f1,6 -d'/' | tr / =) ; do echo -n $i ; sudo apt-cache show $i | grep '^Size:' | cut -d: -f2 ; done | awk '{ total+=$2 } END { print total / 1000 / 1000 }'` and the output is *very* near to value provided by apt upgrade. The *Size* value in apt-cache show might be the size of the .deb package.